# My search pipe filter don't update my template when my data changes

Tags: angular, search, pipe

I'm using this filter pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'search'
})
export class SearchPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: any[], field: string, value: string): any[] {
    if (!items) {
        return [];
    }
    if (!field || !value) {
        return items;
    }

    return items.filter(singleItem =>
        singleItem[field].toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase())
    )}
}
```

**Input:**

```
<input placeholder="Nome do produto" [(ngModel)]="anunciosFiltro.name" type="text" name="filtra" id="filtra">
```

I have this table that i apply this pipe filter:

```
<div *ngFor="let tabelaAnuncioContas of sortedData?.Contas; let a = index" >
    <table>
      <tr *ngFor="let anuncio of tabelaAnuncioContas.Anuncio.products | search: 'name' : anunciosFiltro.name; let i = index">

         <td>

            <svg class="componenteTabelaResponsivo" matTooltip="Anúncio ativo" *ngIf="anuncio.status == 'enabled' && anuncio.associations[0].status == 'linked'" style="width:24px;height:24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                                <path fill="rgb(161,196,66)" d="M12,2A10,10 0 0,1 22,12A10,10 0 0,1 12,22A10,10 0 0,1 2,12A10,10 0 0,1 12,2Z" />
            </svg>

         </td>

      </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

My pipe filter is working normally but when i filter and make a http requisition that changes the data of my table `(sortedData)`, the filter don't update the data:

```
changeDataTable(){   
 this.sortedData.Contas[this.indexContaAlterada].Anuncio.products[this.indexAnuncioAlterado].status = status;
}
```

My `status` in template persist in the initial value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pipe needs to be impure:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'search',
  pure: false
})
```

https://angular.io/guide/pipes#pure-and-impure-pipes

Comment: Don't work for me.
I fixed using a for() to check the real index of my array and change the property:

          for(let i=0;i<this.sortedData.Contas[this.indexContaAlterada].Anuncio.products.length;i++){
            if(this.sortedData.Contas[this.indexContaAlterada].Anuncio.products[i].sku == anuncio.sku){
              this.sortedData.Contas[this.indexContaAlterada].Anuncio.products[i].status = status
            }
          }

Comment: I'm open for other ways to do this

Comment: if the problem was the "real" index (I haven't debugged your code as impure pipes are a commun reason for not updated views), then probably trackBy option in ngFor could help

Comment: Yes, the problem is the index. I will try with trackby

Comment: I understand the pure: false, this work when the element is removed in template

Answer (score 0):

This is related to how pipes are handled, and mainly because of the difference of pure and impure pipes, as described [here](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#pure-and-impure-pipes).

You could just set your pipe to impure on the class decorator by doing:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'search',
  pure: false
})
```

But you should **be very care** as how to use it. The first version of angular had both filter and orderBy pipes, which where intentionally removed. The reasons for so are described [here](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe)

So, I would suggest you to avoid using pipes for that if possible. Otherwise, you may make your pipe impure (as shown above) and this will lead to the behaviour you're expecting.

Comment: Don't work for me. I fixed using a for() to check the real index of my array and change the property: for(let i=0;i<this.sortedData.Contas[this.indexContaAlterada].Anuncio.products.length;i++){ if(this.sortedData.Contas[this.indexContaAlterada].Anuncio.products[i].sku == anuncio.sku){ this.sortedData.Contas[this.indexContaAlterada].Anuncio.products[i].status = status } }